# Laravel 5.6.9 - database count gives different outputs

Tags: sql, laravel

Does anyone know why these two ways to count numbers of users in my table give different answers when i run them in tinker?

> > > App\Models\User::count()
> > > => 92269

> > > $count = \DB::table('users')->count()
> > > => 92829

Running a SQL query in Sequel Pro gives 92829.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... are you using Soft Deletes on your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `SoftDelete` trait on your `User` model then when you query via the Model it excludes "deleted" entries. You can include them by adding the `withTrashed()` constraint.

```
App\Models\User::withTrashed()->count();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#soft-deleting